# Is there a java library to invoke methods with a given annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, persistence

In our application, we use a graph persistence library which do not implement JPA entity listeners behaviours. In other words, a method annotated with `@PrePersist` will never be called.

As we discovered the need for such a behaviour, I would like to know if there is a java library that could ease things a little ... as an example by returning me a list of objects/methods that need to be called as `@PrePersist` elements. Do you know such libraries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)

> Reflections scans your classpath, indexes the metadata, allows you to query it on runtime and may save and collect that information for many modules within your project.
>
> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types/**methods**/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o annotation parameters matching
> - get all resources matching matching a regular expression